# Xamarin Forms UWP OnPropertyChanged EventHandler not firing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working through a Xamarin Forms tutorial what only shows code for IOS & Android.

In the code it assigns the OnPropertyChanged EventHandler for the view model in the page OnAppearing() method when the page is navigated to, and in  IOS & Android this works correctly and the correct method is called.

However using this in a UWP app the method isn't called when any property is changed.

I can do a work around in the OnPropertyChanging event, but I'd prefer to find a correct solution

Can anyone suggest a way to get this working correctly?

Thanks

Comment: without seeing your actual code, or knowing which tutorial you're following, it's impossible to say.  Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Yep, in the debugger it shows the EventHandler being set but then nothing else for UWP app

The tutorial is on packtpub.com so can't share

Comment: I suggest you look at some of the official Xamarin samples, or contact the author of the tutorial.  We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: Ok, will do - thanks